# How to make an editor enabled only when the related boolean property is set true

Tags: javascript, c#, html, razor

I'm writing a code in cshtml, to which I'm very new.

I have two radio buttons and one editor. 
The two radio button are bound to a boolean property in the model.
I'd like to make the editor enabled only when the boolean property is set true.
Could you tell me how?

```
@model MyNameSpace.Models.MyModel

<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsManualInput, true)
                Manual Input
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsManualInput, false)
                Automatic Input
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Target Date
            </td>
            <td>
                @* I'd like to make this editor enabled only when model.IsManualInput is true *@
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TargetDate, new { @maxlength = "12" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you wanting the editor to be disabled or enabled *only* on page load? Or are you looking for it to be disabled/enabled as the user selects between the radio buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you need to disable this `input` field only once on page-load, or *every time* the value of the radio buttons is changed.

I've included both examples, just in case.

**For page load only - static**

You could set the `disabled` or `readonly` attribute of the `input`, by the `HtmlAttributes` declaration:

```
<td>
        @* I'd like to make this editor enabled only when model.IsManualInput is true *@

        @if (Model.IsManualInput)
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TargetDate, new { @maxlength = "12" })
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TargetDate, new { @maxlength = "12",
                                                             @disabled = "disabled" })
        }
</td>
```

For `readonly`, set the `readonly = "readonly"` instead/also.

**When the user switches between radio buttons - dynamic**

This expands on my first example, so your `input` is always rendered correctly on page load, first.

Give the "Manual Input" radio button an ID, so you can reference this easily:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsManualInput, true,
                     htmlAttributes: new { @id = "manual-input-radio" })
```

Also, give the "Target Date" field an ID, so you can reference that, too:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TargetDate, new { @maxlength = "12",
                                                 @disabled = "disabled",
                                                 @id = "target-date-input"})
```

Then, create a script to add or remove the attribute (this uses jQuery, but you can tweak it to use vanilla JS if you like):

```
$('input:radio[name="IsManualInput"]').change(function() {
    if ($(#manual-input-radio).attr('checked') == 'checked')
    {
        $('#target-date-input').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#target-date-input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

This will fire when the state of the `IsManualInput` radio group changes. It then checks if the `#manual-input-radio` is "checked", and sets or removes the `#target-date-input`'s `disabled` attribute.

Hope this helps!

**ALSO**: *SPOILER ALERT* - Just for the sake of clarity - if you are using the above script, ensure you're referencing the [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) library

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'd like to switch the editors state every time the user clicks the radio buttons. Your script partly worked for me, but the editor state changes only when the first time the radio button is checked, never changing again how many times the radio is checked. Is it enough if I add the script in the following way? `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">`

Comment: I see. I think it has something to do with the `change()` event being fired only when it is selected. In this case, when you're un-selecting and then re-selecting it *is* running the code, but the condition will always be true. Let me have a think and I'll see what I can come up with :)

Comment: TBH, I never really declare the language in my scripts - just `<script type="text/javascript">` does it for me

Comment: Could you try `id`ing up *both* radio buttons, and doing 2 `$('#...').click(function () { ... } );`; e.g. one for `'#manual-input-radio` and one for `#automatic-input-radio` - each one enabling/disabling respectively? If that works, I'll update my answer

Comment: I already gave it a try myself, but it didn't work (worked only when the first time). What is more, I replaced EditorFor with TextBoxFor, since the former does not support html attributes.

Comment: Good spot. I'll update my answer, just to clarify this :)

Comment: Yes, I'm referencing the jQuery library, in the following way, for example. `<link href="~/Web/css/Core/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: That is only the jQuery UI. You need to also make sure you've got the jQuery JS lib - e.g. `<script src="~/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>` - you can reference a local copy or use a CDN version

Comment: I copied the contents of this website (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js) and added a reference to it just like <script src="@Url.Content("~/Web/js/Core/jquery.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>. But it still does not work...

Comment: You don't need `@Url.Content`; just `src="~/Web/js/Core/jquery.min.js" ...` will work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115200/discussion-between-geoff-james-and-user4134476).

Answer (score 0):

You could just do something like this:

```
<td>
    @* I'd like to make this editor enabled only when model.IsManualInput is true *@
    @if(model.IsManualInput)
    {
        Html.EditorFor(model => model.TargetDate, new { @maxlength = "12" })
    }
    else
    {
        Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TargetDate)
    }
</td>
```

Alternatively, if using MVC 5.1:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TargetDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { disabled = model.IsManualInput ? "enabled" : "disabled" } })
```

The decision is made server side as opposed to relying on the client.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options. Number 1 is you could decide whether to render an editor or not based on the `IsManualInput`:

```
@if(model.IsManualInput)
{
    Html.EditorFor(model => model.TargetDate, new { @maxlength = "12" })
}
else
{
    Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TargetDate)
}
```

Another approach would be to render `disabled` property, based on the `IsManualInput`. First initialize the additional data:

```
@{
    var additionalData = new ExpandoObject() {};
    additionalData.maxlength = "12";
    if (model.IsManualInput)
    {
        additionalData.htmlAttributes = new { .disabled = string.Empty };
    }
}
```

- You need to import `System.Dynamic` namespace to employ the `ExpandoObject`

Then pass those `additionalData` as a second parameter to `EditorFor`:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TargetDate, additionalData)
```